# My teacher always lies

Tags: grammar

"the Man claimed to have link with the recent incident"

Please help me explaining the sentence or phrase above.
For me the sentence should be written "the man was/is claimed to....."

Am i right? If so why my teacher warn me no to omit auxiliary verbs?

Comment: [My teacher always lies.=correction] You claim something. Your teacher **is not lying**.

Comment: The man is claimed [by others] to be linked to the recent incident. Compared to: The main claims [says] to be linked to the recent incident. Two different things.

Comment: "The ship docked in Port" means the ship itself docked in Port or the ship is docked in Port and auxiliary verb omitted here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The man claimed to be linked to the recent incident. [He claimed, active verb]

There is no auxiliary verb in the sentence above.

- It was claimed [dummy subject, passive use of claim]
- **It was or is claimed** (**by** the authorities) that he was linked to the incident.
- The ship docked at the port. [active verb used to distinguish it from some other action].
- The ship sailed through the canal.
- The ship was docked at the port. [passive, meaning: was moored there, who docked it is not given]
- The car was parked in the garage. [passive, it was there, who parked it is not given]
- The car was parked by the chauffeur in the garage. [passive, with agent]
- The ship was docked by the captain but is usually docked by the first mate. [passive,with agent]

In sentences like: the car was parked there, the ship was docked there, the verbs: was parked, was docked refer to the state or condition of a thing but not who performed the action that resulted in their being in that state.

Generally: x was/were + past participle is either a passive sentence or used to describe a state or condition of the subject of the sentence.

When you see who did something to someone or something, that is called the agent.
The car was parked by the chauffeur [agent] in the garage.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate that

Comment: Would you like to explain what the sentence means "ECB expected to cut deposit rate to at least minus 0.5%"? It's active or passive?

Comment: Please make things clear, I'm so confused

Comment: @MuhamedBešić That sentence is a a press release sub-title or tv news scrolled at the bottom of a TV screen. They have left out the **"is"** on purpose to shorten it. ***ECB is expected [by some group of people] to cut the deposit rate** etc. It is passive. The press will often do that to save space. I can see why this is confusing to you.

Comment: Is there something omitted inside your explanation? "Sub-title or tv news (is) scrolled"

Comment: Please help me I'm still so confused, i appreciate your explanation

Comment: You are misreading me: 1) press release sub-tile OR 2) TV news [that is]  **scrolled at the bottom of a TV screen**. 2) is a full phrase. You are now confusing verbs with clauses. Children [who were] **seen at the park** were playing football. Sometimes we can shorten clauses like that.

Comment: Thank you lambie, actually i have never read grammar before, i learn English reading articles and informal writings. For me expression is everything, as i learn English by reading, usually omitted lots of words especially, so called auxiliary verb and still everyone understands

Comment: Your explanation is great, won't forget as you explain that confused for several days

Comment: Before i go i got one more question is wherever i go i usually get informal English, should i learn formal wasting my time or my informal ok enough?

Comment: Anyway you great as you explain my confusion

Comment: Have a nice day

Comment: @MuhamedBešić You need to clean up your grammar. Your sentences are not idiomatic.  For example: "won't forget as you explain that confused for several days" should be something like this: I won't forget **this** as you explained **what was confusing me** for several days.

Comment: Yea i know thank you

Comment: Hi Lambie, sorry to bother you, I got a question, as you said "Children [who were] seen at the park were playing football", "who were" is omitted here. It can be possible the "ship [which/that is] docked at the port" and "which/that is omitted here as well"? For me now the sentence looks passive or express condition instead "the ship itself docked at the Port". That means a sentence can express multiple meanings depending on context?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104417/discussion-between-muhamed-besic-and-lambie).

Answer (score 0):

> the man claimed to have link*s* with the recent incident

The man himself claimed to have links with the incident.

> the man is/was claimed to have links with the recent incident

Somebody else claimed the man has links with the incident.

Comment: This is the second time you have comment "You never read newpaper".  This sounds rude. Why do you say this? Please remember that we are not paid to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, i was so frustrated and confused